# compare snapshot with maven versions of Lucene-Appengine project

Tags: maven, google-app-engine, gradle, lucene

I have been trying to get Lucene-Appengine working for quite some time now. My latest error is

> com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService invokeServiceMethod:
>   org.apache.lucene.store.BaseDirectory: method ()V not found
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.lucene.store.BaseDirectory:
>   method ()V not found    at
>   com.googlecode.luceneappengine.GaeDirectory.(GaeDirectory.java:81)

Since this is likely due to library mismatch, I need some help deciding what to do.

I am using Android Studio and so I am getting the project as

```
compile 'com.googlecode.luceneappengine:luceneappengine:2.0.0'
```

However, there seems to be no such project in the [compatibility matrix](https://code.google.com/p/lucene-appengine/wiki/LuceneAppEngineVersions)(bottom of page).

Will somebody please guide me? Here is my complete list of import presently. If you mean to help, please be exact in your response as to which import I should replace.

```
compile 'com.googlecode.luceneappengine:luceneappengine:2.0.0'
compile 'org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:5.0.0'
compile 'org.apache.lucene:lucene-analyzers-common:5.0.0'
compile 'org.apache.lucene:lucene-queries:5.0.0'
compile 'org.apache.lucene:lucene-queryparser:5.0.0'
compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.12'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are watching the older project page, the new one is [here](https://code.google.com/p/luceneappengine/wiki/LuceneAppEngineVersions), and now the project has been completely migrated under [github](https://github.com/UltimaPhoenix/luceneappengine), with the [wiki](https://github.com/UltimaPhoenix/luceneappengine/wiki/Versions) too.

`Lucene 5.0.0` is supported by `luceneappengine 3.0.0`. You can checkout a full lucene project example [here](https://github.com/UltimaPhoenix/lucene-appengine-examples/).